# Which domino is heavier?

Tags: dominoes

I purchased a set of double-six dominoes. It has a manual which points to the heaviness of the dominoes. It says that a double-six is the heaviest domino and the double blank is the lightest. The same is said on this website ([link](http://www.domino-games.com/domino-rules/domino-basics.html)) dedicated to dominoes.

I can't find on Google which is heavier: a 1-6 or a 3-4. Can an experienced player tell me the answer and the reasoning behind it?

Comment: It depends on the set.  If you're using dominos where the marks are depressed, than the double-blank is the heaviest because it has less holes in it and therefore takes more material to make. but otherwise, the double-6 is the heaviest because it has more paint on it

Comment: @SamIam, at first I also thought that the question was talking about actual weight, but upon some research, I have found that in Dominios, the term "weight" refers to refers simply to the number of pips on a domino, and nothing to do with how heavy it is!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Neither, both have a weight of 7.**

Domino [weight values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominoes#Tiles_and_suits) are determined by counting the pips on bound sides. Heavier tiles left unplayed in hand, will earn your opponents more points in many Domino variants.

> The sum of the two values, i.e. the total number of pips, may be referred to as the rank or weight of a tile, and a tile with more pips may be called heavier than a lighter tile with fewer pips.